# Work of LSZ reduction formula

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, s-matrix-theory, virtual-particles

I want to know the mechanism of the LSZ reduction formula. The left side will have $\langle f|S|i\rangle$ and the right side has Fourier transform of $(\Box+m^2)$ times multiplication of *Heisenberg fields* under time ordering. Intuitively the LHS creates and destroys some particles but $\langle \Omega |T{\phi(x)...}||\Omega \rangle $ only produces virtual particles. So, somehow this recipe converts virtual particles at vertices into real particles. But how?

Comment: What do you mean by "only produces virtual particles"?

Comment: Since something is totally contacting will have non zero vacuum expectation value, this RHS actually produces virtual particles since every path is determined by Feynman propagators

Comment: Virtual particles become real because of infinite integration limits: virtual particles always become real in infinity.

Comment: If you're looking for a more rigorous treatment on QFT, including of course the LSZ theorem, take a look at Duncan's QFT textbook.